# Probability of winning when at least one 6 appears when 6 fair dice are rolled

Tags: probability, permutations, dice

> In a game there are three teams. They are asked to throw dice, and for each team to win:
>
> - A needs one 6 from 6 dice
> - B needs two 6's from 12 dice
> - C needs three 6's from 18 dice
>
> What are the chances of A winning?

I thought it was $1-\left(\frac56\right)^2$, but my book gives the answer as $\frac23$.

Comment: Teams B and C are irrelevant in this question.

Comment: Some details may be missing.

Comment: could you make the rules clearer please - you say they throw two dice - how many times?  Are they taking turns?  are the results just from their dice throws?  Can you see why I don't understand your question?   -  you risk being down voted if you post partial or vague questions like this!

Comment: you might be misreading the question, if they throw SIX dice then their chances of getting at least 1 six is 1 - (5/6) ^6    -   you've missed that they have 6 not 2 dice somewhere

Comment: @pi66 - I don't see how we know that!  What if they get their 2 from 12 or 3 from 18?  Does that at least tie the game?  Team B has a good chance of achieving their target and at least tieing the game - see my problem?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have displayed the question as is .  We  have to find the answer based on the given premise. The answer given is 0.67. I am also trying to find the steps leading to answer.

Comment: @harry - yes but the question appears to follow on from some previous question that we can't see - ok I won't vote it down myself anyway!  But this sort of question can be a frustration to people helping out!

Comment: @harry - obviously you have to understand the question yourself first, otherwise you won't understand the steps - I don't really understand the question

Comment: @AndrewDeighton True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: What is the probability that for a particular die, the number appearing is not a $6$?

What is the probability that for all six dice, the number appearing is not a $6$? (It's the previous answer raised to the sixth power.)

What is the probability that for at least one of the six dice, the number appearing is a $6$?
(It's one minus the previous answer.)